# Compare two different column in sql server to get result

Tags: sql-server

i'm stuck in problem, i want to get result who's value falls between SlabFrom & Slabto

Query:

```sql
Declare @Userinputvalue Decimal(11,6);
Set     @Userinputvalue = '700001';

select * from _TaxRate

where   SlabTo >= @Userinputvalue and SlabFrom <= @Userinputvalue
```

TABLE DATA (EXISTING DATA)

```
SRNO    SlabFrom    SlabTo  Perage
-----------------------------------------
1      0             600000    0
2      600001        1200000   5
3      1200001       1500000   7
4      1500001       2000000   10
```

Above Result

No Data Found / Blank

But, I Need suppose row number two because my user input value found between (600001 - 1200000), but above query return no data.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: First it is unusual to specify a DECIMAL datatype which is a number and give a string value !

Comment: Second, we do not know what datatype your table's columns have...

Comment: `SET @Userinputvalue = '700001';` is going to immediately fail. The value is too large for a `decimal(11,6)`. The *largest* value a `decimal(11,6)` can store in `99999.999999`, where as the value `700001` is about 7 times larger than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code you'll see why

```
Declare @Userinputvalue Decimal(11,6);
Set     @Userinputvalue = '700001';
select @Userinputvalue;
```

The result is arithmetic overflow.  Decimal(11, 6) is not wide enough to store '700001'

Suppose all of the columns are integers, then it works without issues

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTest;
go
create table #tTest(
  SRNO               int,
  SlabFrom           int,
  SlabTo             int,
  Perage             int);
  
insert #tTest(SRNO, SlabFrom, SlabTo, Perage) values
(1, 0, 600000, 0),
(2, 600001, 1200000, 0),
(3, 1200001, 1500000, 0),
(4, 1500001, 2000000, 0);
```

Query

```
Declare @Userinputvalue int;
Set     @Userinputvalue = 700001;

select *
from #tTest t 
where SlabTo >= @Userinputvalue
      and SlabFrom <= @Userinputvalue;
```

Output

```
SRNO    SlabFrom    SlabTo  Perage
2       600001      1200000 0
```

Comment: I would remove the stringification of @Userinputvalue for completeness.

Comment: I updated.  It implicitly converts but you're more correct.  Thnx!